# .Net Core DI using Func with ISP

Tags: dependency-injection, solid-principles

Hi I am using one common interface between two services. Initially the interface was common between two services ServiceA and ServiceB but as it grew I realized that ServiceB won't need all the methods available in the interface so I wanted to follow ISP.

Before (when I was using common interface) it was easy to inject DI and decide which Concrete implementation of the interface would be used on runtime based on some parameter passed from the api.
Below is the example of I was doing it before based on the ServiceProvider. ServiceA and ServiceB use the common interface so in MyRepo it is easy for me to just call the method and not worrying about who is implementing it.

**Statrtup.cs**

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ServiceA>();
services.AddSingleton<ServiceB>();

services.AddTransient<Func<ServiceProvider, IBaseService>>(serviceProvider => key =>
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case ServiceProvider.A:
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceA>();

        case ServiceProvider.B:
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceB>();

        default:
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }
});

public interface IServiceA : IBaseService
{
    Task<Response> GetShoppingMethodsAsync(
        ShoppingMethodsRequest request,CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    Task<Response> GetTrolleyAsync(
        TrolleyRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public interface IServiceB : IBaseService
{
    Task<Response> GetShoppingMethodsAsync(
        ShoppingMethodsRequest request,CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    Task<Response> GetTrolleyAsync(
        TrolleyRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}


public class MyRepo    {
    private readonly Func<ServiceProvider, IBaseervice> _service;

    public MyRepo(
        IMapper mapper, IPaymentOptionsService paymentOptionsService,
        Func<ServiceProvider, IBaseService> service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

    public async Task ConsumeService(Provider p)
    {
       var resp = await _service(P).GetShoppingMethodsAsync(myrequest);
    }
}
```

The problem with above approach is if I want to apply ISP then in the ConsumeService I would need to know which interface type it is before calling it's method, and for that I need to check and cast like below

```cs
    public class MyRepo    {
    private readonly Func<ServiceProvider, IBaseervice> _service;

    public MyRepo(
        IMapper mapper, IPaymentOptionsService paymentOptionsService,
        Func<ServiceProvider, IBaseService> service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

     public async Task ConsumeService(Provider p)
     {
        var getService =  _service(P);
        if(getService is IServiceA serviceA)
        {
            var resp = await serviceA.GetShoppingMethodsAsync(myrequest);
        }
     }
   }

public class ServiceA:IServiceA
{
    public Task<Response> GetShoppingMethodsAsync(
        ShoppingMethodsRequest request,CancellationToken cancellationToken) { }

    public Task<Response> GetTrolleyAsync(
        TrolleyRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken){ } 
}

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    public Task<Response> ProcessAsync(
        Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) { }
}
```

Is there any other way to deal with this problem, OR could I return the casted service directly from the DI. Thanks

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer, because the answer depends on a lot of details surrounding the design of your application, which you didn't provide. But concerning the SOLID principles, `MyRepo` might violate the Liskov Substitution Principle. You can instead try to inject `IServiceA` directly into `MyRepo`.

Comment: Thanks Steven, sorry for the insufficient details, I have edited the original post to explain the problem in detail, please let me know what else details you need. The problem in injecting the IServceA directly into MyRepo is it would then need to know about the extra parameter before hand which decides the concrete implementation of the interface. I am lean to make it generic call. Please advise. Thanks